# I pass a variable to ejs but still throw Uncaught ReferenceError why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, web-frontend, uncaught-reference-error

I pass a productId but still get Reference error in ejs why is that happening?

**Script in frontend:**

```
<script> 
(typeof <%= productId %> != "undefined" ? productId: -1 )
</script>
```

**Another Try:**

```
if(typeof <%= productId %> != "undefined"){
  const productId = productId
} else{
  const productId = -1
}
```

**Error message:**

```
fall-look:194 Uncaught ReferenceError: look is not defined
    at fall-look:194:14
```

**Catched error with try- catch:**

[image: error image]

**Where error happened:**

[image: error console img]

We can clearly see a productId is defined but still throw productId is not defined error why is this happened?